# Как вывести в консоль, значение кнопки при клике, если их несколько? С разными значениями

Tags: javascript, html

Вот коды из JavaScript и HTML, нужно чтобы в консоли выводилось значение Value, однако при клике пишет только left
Чего не хватает?

```
let buttons_1 = document.getElementsByClassName('position_text');
for (let i = 0; i < buttons_1.length; i++){
    buttons_1[i].onclick = change_size;
}
function change_size(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(document.querySelector('.position_text').value)
}
```

Это HTML:

```
<div class="box_size">
                    <button type="submit" class="position_text" onclick=change_size(this) value="left">Left</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="position_text" onclick=change_size(this) value="center">Center</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="position_text" onclick=change_size(this) value="right">Right</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="position_text" onclick=change_size(this) value="left">40px</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="position_text" onclick=change_size(this) value="left">45px</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="position_text" onclick=change_size(this) value="left">50px</button>
                </div>
```

Comment: console.log(e.target.value)

Comment: Всего хватает, замените document.querySelector('.position_text'), на this